# Hide() and show() on window resize in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use `.hide()` to hide the anchor element when it is less than `500px width` and `.show()` again when the window size is greater than `500px width`.

So it changes depending on the window size.

*application.js*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var windowWidth = $(window).width();

 function checkWidth() {
    if (windowWidth < 500) {
        $("#down-arrow a").hide()
    }
    if (windowWidth > 500){
        $("#down-arrow a").show()
    }
 }
 checkWidth() ;

 $(window).resize(function() {
   checkWidth() ;
 });
});
```

*index.html*

```
<div id="down-arrow">
   <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Doing this in javascript is like driving a bus up a flight of stairs! Use media queries, such as wmehanna's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get the current width inside `checkWidth()` function so that it's the latest value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 function checkWidth() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth <= 500) {
        $("#down-arrow a").hide();
    } else {
        $("#down-arrow a").show();
    }
 }
 checkWidth();

 $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

Probably should also change one of the comparisons to include the `500` value so you do something when the width is exactly `500`.  And, I switched the code to use an if/else rather than two `if` statements.

You could also just use `.toggle()` and pass it a boolean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 function checkWidth() {
    $("#down-arrow a").toggle($(window).width() > 500);
 }
 checkWidth();

 $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

And, you could implement all of this with CSS media query rules too and not have to use Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Using Javascript to show/hide a DOM element is not reccommended since the best way to acheive this is to use css @Mediaquery properties.

Here's an example :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #down-arrow a{
        display : none;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the love of all that is good, this is the correct approach, please use media queries for this!

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery.Get current width using `$(window).width()`

```
$(window).resize(setDivVisibility);
function setDivVisibility(){
     if (($(window).width()) < '500'){  
     $('#down-arrow a').css('display','none');  
     } else {  
     $('#down-arrow a').css('display','block');  
     } 
 }
```

Using CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {
    #down-arrow a{display:none;}
}
```